# How to convert Class object to data structure `Map` or a `List of Maps` in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to convert an `Object` type to a `Map` or a `List of Maps` in **Dart**, so the *variables become key/value pairs*?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json (this creates a Map or List of Maps and then an additional step `json.encode(...)` creates the actual JSON string from Maps)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Based on my experience, dart does not provide that kind of system yet. So, basically we create function like `toMap()` that manually convert the object to a key-value pair of map.

For example:

```
class Human {
  String name;
  int age;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'age': age,
    };
  }
}
```

So, later when you have a `Human` object, you just can call `human.tomap()`.

I do this in most of my entity classes.

Comment: can you explain why you use "dynamic" instead of "int"?

Comment: he is using dynamic because value might be a string or integer or boolean. declaring dynamic type will assign the type of variable during the run time

Comment: do I need to make getter after to access it or?

Comment: @OunknownO Nope.  Just do `Map<String, dynamic> humanMap = yourHumanObj.toMap()`

Comment: @OunknownO - Basically you can also write `toMap` method as a getter. In that case, you would say `yourHumanObj.toMap`

Answer (score 7):

This is a much easier and error-prone-free approach, (And if you are already using these classes as DTO objects that need to be serialized this is a double win).

Add the following 3 dependenciess in your pubsec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  json_annotation:^3.1.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^1.10.11
  json_serializable: ^3.2.5
```

In the class that you want to get the Map for do the following.

```
part 'person.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Person{
String name;
String surname;
Person(this.name,this.surname);

//make sure you have the (Just change part of the method name to your class name)

 factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$PersonFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonToJson(this);//Replace 'Person' with your class name


}
```

That's it, you then just have to run the following command in your terminal so flutter can generate the "toMap()" method for you.

```sh
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Then use it like such.

```
var person =Person('somename','some surname');//This is object
Map personMap =person.toJson();
```

Ez.
This is a much better approach especially if you have complex objects with multiple objects inside. Just make sure that each nested object contains these changes as well (JsonSerializable annotation, the 'part 'class.g.dart'' , and the 2 methods)

NOTE: that if property changes are made to the classes, just run this command again.

```sh
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Comment: Amazing! This should definitely be the top and accepted answer!

Comment: This answer overreaches by converting the field values to like maps as well. To avoid converting the whole object to JSON, you could omit `explicitToJson: true` in the JsonSerializable annotation. In that case, it remains unclear how to get both conversion options at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out this package [class_to_map](https://pub.dev/packages/class_to_map)

```dart
import 'package:class_to_map/class_to_map.dart';
class Test {
  String val1 = "value 1";
  int val2 = 2;
  Map val3 = {"a": "another value"};
}
print(Test().toMap());

// converting map to class
{"val1": 'value 1', "val2": 2, "val3": {"a": "another value"} }.toClass<Test>();
```

Comment: is this method will refer the changes to other files also?
eg: i change the file here (converting to map, change the value, converting it back to class), would that affect if i cal this class elsewhere?

Comment: No, it won't affect elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
var data = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3",
};

var myMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(data);
print(myMap);
```

With dynamic in Map<String, **dynamic**> we can have the values of the map of any type. In the example above, it is String.

Comment: This converts a map to a map, not an object (non-class instance) to a map

Comment: I meant non-map class instance