# Convert class variables to a map in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class A extends State<A>{
String name1 = '';
String name2 = '';
String name3 = '';

}
```

I've 3 methods that return `Strings` that are assigned to the variables with a `setState`. What is the best way to put these values in the map like this

```
{'name1': 'Tom',
 'name2':'Mike',
 'name3':'Jim'
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a [HashMap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-collection/HashMap-class.html)?

Comment: Could do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949087/how-to-convert-class-object-to-data-structure-map-or-a-list-of-maps-in-dart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a function like this :

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
  'name1': this.name1,
  'name2': this.name2,
  'name3': this.name3,
};
```

Sample how to use it :

```dart
final itemA = A('myName 1', 'myName 2', 'myName 3');
Map<String, dynamic> myMap = itemA.toMap();
```

I use this function to convert my object to a json personally.