# FLUTTER,DART: How can I convert list<Model> to map

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I want to convert the List to Map and get only 'CourseName', how can I do this?

Here is the Model

```
`class Course {
  final int courseCategoryId;
  final int courseSubCategoryId;
  final int courseId;
  final Color onlineTrueColor;
  final String coverImgCourse;
  final String courseName;
  final String courseTeaserText;
  final int courseTutorId;
  final String courseGrads;
  final int coursePrice;
  final String courseCashBack;
  final bool isCourseOnline;
  final String courseDescription;

  Course ( {
    this.courseDescription,
    this.courseCategoryId,
    this.courseSubCategoryId,
    this.courseId,
    this.onlineTrueColor,
    this.coverImgCourse,
    this.courseName,
    this.courseTeaserText,
    this.courseTutorId,
    this.courseGrads,
    this.coursePrice,
    this.courseCashBack,
    this.isCourseOnline,
  });
}  `
```

(I need to convert it to map, cuz I need this for my dropdown list, it only works with map, if you think that there's could be another solution please share it with me)

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: ButtonTheme(
                alignedDropdown: true,
                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  isDense: true,
                  hint: Text('Выберите категорию'),
                  value: _selected,
                  onChanged: (String newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selected = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                  items: _course.map((Map map) {
                    return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: map["id"].toString(),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget> [
                          
                          Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                              child: Text(map['courseName']),
                            )
                          ],
                        ));
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Class object to data structure \`Map\` or a \`List of Maps\` in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949087/how-to-convert-class-object-to-data-structure-map-or-a-list-of-maps-in-dart)

Comment: Possible duplicate. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949087/how-to-convert-class-object-to-data-structure-map-or-a-list-of-maps-in-dart

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to convert it to a map. Using a list is fine.
If you notice, in the end of your items, after you build them the .toList() method is called. In the end you are creating a list of DropdownMenuItem.

Solution: You can use the List.generate() method and build all your items directly from a list.

This is how your code should look like:

```
 items: List.generate(yourList.length, (index) => 
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: yourList[index].id.toString(),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget> [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Text(yourList[index].courseName),
                )
               ],
              )
             );
            ),
```