# Any way to iterate all elements of a record in Dart

Tags: dart

I want to iterate through each element in a record by converting it to an Iterable like List or directly. Does anyone have a solution or workaround for this?

I have a function that will return a few Objects, and I want to iterate over all to select the best one. Something like this:

```
final (Object, Object, Object, Object) res = getRes();
Object? best = null;
for (final value in res) {
  final temp = process(value);
  if (best == null || temp > best) best = temp;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to iterate over a `Record` or to convert an arbitrary one to a `List`.  Usually you wouldn't want to since they are heterogeneous. (They also might have named fields.) If you want to iterate, then use a `List`.  If you must use a `Record`, then you always could write a conversion to a `List` specific to that `Record` type.  For example: `[record.$1, record.$2, record.$3, record.$4]`.

Comment: Dart records are more like classes than collections, so it doesn't make sense to iterate over them. You can convert an object to a map based on the object's class in a few ways - here's some discussion on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949087/how-to-convert-class-object-to-data-structure-map-or-a-list-of-maps-in-dart You might be able to do something similar for a record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing built into the language or platform libraries which is better than:

```dart
for (final value in [res.$1, res.$2, res.$3, res.$4]) {
  ...
}
```

It only works if you know the shape of the record.

The real question is why you return a record of similarly-typed objects instead of a list?

A record makes sense when you have *differently* typed values, with different meanings.
If you have similarly typed values, where your code can end up using either of them, and you want to iterate over the values and treat them homogenously, that's precisely what a list is for.